# Change severals divs css onload with jquery (this)

Tags: jquery, css

When the page loads, i try to change the margin-top of each .partition div.
I have tried to use $(this) but i can't find the good solution :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.partition').css({
      'marginTop':  - ($(this).height() / 2)
      });
  });
```

Any idea ?
Many thanks !

Comment: you can use the exact CSS properties syntax (i.e `margin-top`) when using `css()` jQuery's method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `.each()`. You can return the value from a function directly:

```
$('.partition').css({
    'marginTop': function () {
        return -($(this).height() / 2)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap that in an `each` function.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.partition').each(function(){
           $(this).css({
              'marginTop':  - ($(this).height() / 2)
           });
      });
   });
```

`$(this)` has no meaning otherwise. [JSBin code](http://jsbin.com/qidutabojano/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through all your divs with class partition and apply css. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.partition').each(function(){
        $(this).css({
      'marginTop':  - ($(this).height() / 2)
      });
    });
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/hk1mccxs/)**